# How to circumvent Here Maps JS API screentogeo bug with mousewheel zooming?

Tags: here-api, heremaps

If one zooms out and in on a map with mousewheel, Here Maps breaks or at least its coordinate system goes asunder.

I added map.screenToGeo(ev.currentPointer.viewportX, ev.currentPointer.viewportY) to my map.addEventListener('tap') function, and the lat,lon results varied after mousewheel zooming even though I didn't change the physical X,Y coords (viewportX and viewportY stayed constant).

Some debug:

```
Screencoord: 660, 660
mg {lat: 61.48160495921855, lng: 23.7620574375982}
mousewheel
mousewheel
Screencoord: 660, 660
mg {lat: 61.47521004787344, lng: 23.76205743759826}
```

Any suggestions how to circumvent this? Implement my own screentogeo?

Comment: Clarification: the zoom level is the same before and after the zoom out/zoom in.

Answer (score 0):

This is a expected behavior and there is nothing to do with mouse wheel behavior. e.g. if you click on a map when the zoom level is 0 then the precession is very bad because under one pixel of the map could be a big map area and when you zoom in to zoom level 18 for the same screen coordinates. Therefore for different zoom levels, there will be always the same screen coordinates but the geo coordinates will be changed.

You can try below snippet code:

```
map.addEventListener('tap', e => {
let c = map.screenToGeo(e.currentPointer.viewportX, e.currentPointer.viewportY);
console.log("tap:", e.currentPointer.viewportX, e.currentPointer.viewportX, c);

//map.addObject(new H.map.Marker(c));
});
```

Comment: You missunderstood the question. Step 1: zoom level x, pointer at lat/lon (a,b).
Step 2: roll/zoom out, do not move mouse pointer. Step 3: roll/zoom in, do not move mouse pointer. Step 4. Press click. Result: neigbouring polygon catches the 'tap' event. Excpected result: the polygon under the mouse pointer catches the 'tap' event. Workaround: after zooming out and in, move mouse back and forth on the map and click - the right polygon receives the event.